# Kendo sortable issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-sortable

In my project i'm using a kendo sortable to do the reorder of my image thumbnail. It is filter by the thumbnail div class "col-md-6 up". Everything is fine except that i have a dropdownlist inside the div which is not working now when clicking it.

This is mycode:

```
 $("#ImageListView").kendoSortable({
        filter: ">div.col-md-6.up",
        cursor: "move",
        autoScroll: true,
        placeholder: function (element) {
            return element.clone().css("opacity", 0.1);
        },
        hint: function (element) {
            return element.clone().removeClass("k-state-selected");
        }
        });
```

And this is my thumbnail div:

```
div class="col-md-6 up">
<div>
<label class="docLabel" id="docLabe style="display:none;float:right;">Dropdown</label>
<select class="docSelect" id="docSelect" style="display:none;float:right;">
  <option value="A">A</option>
</select>
</div>

</div>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [ignore](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/sortable/configuration/ignore) configuration of `kendoSortable` to make it work. I would do it like :

```
$("#ImageListView").kendoSortable({
    filter: ">div.col-md-6.up",
    cursor: "move",
    autoScroll: true,
    ignore: "#docSelect",
    placeholder: function (element) {
        return element.clone().css("opacity", 0.1);
    },
    hint: function (element) {
        return element.clone().removeClass("k-state-selected");
    }
});
```